# substitute a join for a character that ends a line

Tags: search, replace, join

when pasting from a pdf document, words in the original document are being split up, and replaced by a `-` and a line break.    For example:

```
alternative specifications. In con-
clusion, these findings
```

I'd like to do a global search and replace to join up these lines.

There are many options that get me part way, for example, `g/-$/join!` 
will deliver

> alternative specifications. In con-clusion,

but I would also like to delete the `-` in the same command.

Seems like it should be really easy, but...

Comment: `:%s/-\n//` or something similar

Comment: Well I was right that it was easy!   thanks